# jquery - fire keyup event after type 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've implemented the following code: (an example here http://jsfiddle.net/MvWV7/3/)

```
  $(".activity_order").keyup(function() {
    var $t = $(this)
    $.map($(".activity_order").not("#"+$t.attr("id")), function(t) {
      if(t.value === $t.val() && $t.val() != ""){
        console.log("number already taken")
        $t.val("")
      }
    })
  })
```

Everything worked as expected until the inputs were more than 10 then the keyup event didn't let me use 2 digit numbers.

A solution I'm taking in consideration is adding a timeout, but I'm not sure if that's the best way. Maybe there's something I'm missing that could make this happen without that timeout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just rework the UI a bit: do not clear the value, but mark it as invalid (maybe with a red background or something) until the issue is corrected.  By the way, you can also use `.not(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function.

```
var t = '';
$(".activity_order").keyup(function () {
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".activity_order").not(self).each(function (t) {
            if (this.value === self.value && self.value != "") {
                // alert("El número ya ha sido tomado")
                self.value = ""
            }
        })
    }, 280);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhdez/

Comment: Well, seems that the only way is adding a timeout. Thanks for your response.